# Is compression an effective way of reading many small files faster?

Tags: python, io, hard-drive

I'm working on an application where it is convenient to store many (around 10^6-10^9) small files (<1K-10K) on disk. I need to iterate over them multiple times for a computation. Would compressing them into a single file would help to significantly reduce the IO bottleneck? I haven't measured different solutions yet, but would like to get pointers on what to expect. This application can easily become IO bound.

Comment: If you compress them into a single file, it will be difficult to access specific files, you'll only be able to process the entire set sequentially.

Comment: I think that we may be able to get away with not supporting random access in this application. Let us say for now that the only thing that I care about is to be able to do a single pass over the files in some arbitrary fixed order.

Comment: Then yes, compressing them together should reduce disk I/O, assuming the data has plenty of redundancy across the files.

Comment: First, is the bottleneck actually your disk throughput, as opposed to, say, seeking between multiple files? If you're on an SSD, or a really wide RAID stripe, you can be reasonably confident it is, but if you're reading off a hard disk or an NFS share or something, you probably need to actually test that. Second, how well does your data compress? Third, with millions of files, the actual OS kernel and filesystem could be getting in the way; just concatenating all the files without any compression might already be all you need. Also: do you (or might you in the futrue) want to parallelize?

Comment: Also, what platform are you on? For example, if you're on Windows in particular, the kernel is definitely seriously getting in the way, but parallelizing properly (throwing a bunch of overlapped operations onto an IOCP) may completely eliminate that. If you're on macOS and using the old HFS+ filesystem, large directories could be most of your problem; etc.

Comment: I would assume that the bottleneck would be seeking between multiple files. The data can is reasonably compressible (2x-16x) in many cases, but I wouldn't assume that that is always the case, meaning that I would like a good default solution that addresses both the compressible and uncompressible cases. Typical setups are SATA disks (with or without SSD) using or some typical HDFS configuration. Preserving multiple file semantics (or at least not destroying it too much) would be great.. Concatenating seems like a good solution easily implementable solution. I work mostly with Linux.

Comment: I don't have a good sense of the orders of magnitude of each of the operations involved in getting the data from disk to memory. Do you know a good reference that I can look up? When you mention parallelization, what do you have in mind specifically; parallelizing the reads? It is definitely conceivable to have IO threads alongside worker threads. I am mostly looking for a good solution (not necessarily optimal for the system that I'm in) that addresses the IO overhead resulting from reading multiple small files rather than one single large file. Space overhead is not a concern for now.